# avoid distortion drawing lines in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, mouse, responsive, lines

I need help trying to represent lines in a canvas. The lines are drawn with the mouse and my problem comes when I try to make the canvas responsive.
When I am drawing lines in the desktop you don't really see the distortion, but when the canvas is loaded in a mobile and I draw an horizontal line, turns out that it keeps the "round shape" of the point, but in vertical lines the point narrows on the sides so the line gets narrower. Because is difficult to explain I show up a picture where I can ilustrate you better:

[image]

I also include an example of the code I am using, so you have a better idea of what I am talking about:

```
//getting the mouse coords    
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
            var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

            scaleX = canvas.width / rect.width,    /*relationship bitmap vs. element for X*/
            scaleY = canvas.height / rect.height;  /*relationship bitmap vs. element for Y*/
            return {
              x: Math.round((evt.clientX - rect.left)*scaleX),
              y: Math.round((evt.clientY - rect.top)*scaleY)
            };

          }
```

and in the context of the canvas I say:

```
ctx.lineJoin="round";
```

The full code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rhwcbwwL/20/
Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You are changing the aspect of the canvas. Use just one scale and set the canvas size to match the display area. `canvas.width = rect.width; canvas.height = rect.height; scale = 1;` (Note that setting canvas size clears the canvas)

Comment: thank you very much!!!, It is working!!